# How are Webservice, SOAP, API, REST and URI related?

Tags: api, rest, soap

I apologize for this very newbie question, but I've never worked with web services before.

I'm attempting to send data to a site that has an API. I'm using an application (not coding something new myself) that has a feature to 'connect using web services.' This app connects to the WSDL site to obtain a list of available services. I enter in the parameters for a specific function and the app effectively builds the URI.

I then attempt to send the URI but receive 'internal server error 500.' I recognize there can be many things wrong with what I'm doing, so I'm seeking some guidance on where to start looking.

The Webservice examples given are all SOAP in XML. As all my app is doing is building the URI, does this mean it will not work or is the app effectively sending it in SOAP behind the scenes? Unfortunately this is not a public app so there is no way for anyone to test.

Would a plug-in such as Chrome's Advanced Rest Client App allow me to connect for testing purposes? I receive the same 'internal server error 500' there. The site I'm connecting to does require authentication in all API calls, but I'm not sure how to enter that in the Advanced Rest Client App. In my app, there are fields for authentication but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

I apologize again for my lack of knowledge...everyone is a newbie at some point.

Comment: If it's WSDL at the site your using, then it is SOAP to that site. You can always add an adapter on your site using whichever technology you prefer to communicate with your users (and then SOAP to make the API calls at the back end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). You can get the latest free version from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/latest/download). There's also a free time-limited evaluation for a "Pro" version at the project site.

Comment: That was a good idea. Using SoapUI, I was able to use the function when properly formatted using the default SOAP structure. However it does not work as REST, I guess you can't use one as the other?

Comment: Correct. They are two fundamentally different ways of doing RPC over HTTP.